# Code not providing desired output

Tags: c#, arrays

I am currently trying to figure out where I went wrong in this logic of code for the assignment. Any remarks or advice would be appreciated!

**The output I keep getting no matter what input I put in keeps giving me**:

> average temperature 0,
>
> highest temperature 5,
>
> lowest temperature 0,
>
> average excluding lowest 0,
>
> number of cold days 10

**First Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace TemperatureAverager
{
class Temperatures
{
    public double[] weeksTemperatures;
    public double threshTemp;
    public double average;
    public double averageExcludingLowest;
    public double highest;
    public double lowest;
    public int numOfThreshs;




    public double[] WeeksTemperatures
    {
        get
        {
            return weeksTemperatures;
        }
    }
    public double ThreshTemp
    {
        get
        {
            return threshTemp;
        }
    }
    public double Average
    {
        set
        {
            average = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return average;
        }
    }
    public double AverageExcludingLowest
    {
        set
        {
            averageExcludingLowest = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return averageExcludingLowest;
        }
    }
    public double Highest
    {
        set
        {
            highest = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return highest;
        }
    }
    public double Lowest
    {
        set
        {
            lowest = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return lowest;
        }
    }
    public int NumberOfThreshs
    {
        set
        {
            numOfThreshs = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return numOfThreshs;
        }
    }
    public Temperatures()
    {
    }
    public Temperatures(double[] wTemperatures, double threshT)
    {
        weeksTemperatures = wTemperatures;
        threshTemp = threshT;
    }
    public double DetermineAverage()
    {
        double average = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) 
        {
            average = average + weeksTemperatures[x];   
        }
        average = average / 7;    
        return average;
    }
    public double DetermineAverageExcludingLowest()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) 
        {
            averageExcludingLowest = averageExcludingLowest + weeksTemperatures[x];
            if (weeksTemperatures[x] < lowest)   
            {
                lowest = weeksTemperatures[x];   
            }
        }
        averageExcludingLowest = ((averageExcludingLowest - lowest) / 7);   // calculate average excluding lowest temperature
        return averageExcludingLowest;
    }
    public double DetermineLowest()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) //Traverse through the week's temperatures
        {
            if (weeksTemperatures[x] < lowest)   //find the lowest temperature of the week
            {
                lowest = weeksTemperatures[x];   //and set it to lowest
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }
    public double DetermineHighest()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) //Traverse through the week's temperatures
        {
            if (weeksTemperatures[x] > highest)  //find the highest temperature of the week
            {
                highest = weeksTemperatures[x];  //and set it to highest
            }
        }
        return highest;
    }
    public double DetermineNumberOfThreshs()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) //Traverse through the week's temperatures
        {
            if (weeksTemperatures[x] < threshTemp)   //find the lowest temperature of the week
            {
                numOfThreshs++;
            }
        }
        return numOfThreshs;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "=====================\nWeekly Statistics\n" + "---------------------\n" + "Average Temperature: " + average + "\nHighest Temperature: "
        + highest + "\nLowest Temperature: " + lowest + "\nAvg. Excl. Lowest: " + averageExcludingLowest + "\n# of Cold Days: " + numOfThreshs + "\n====================="; //Formats and the invoice to be printed
    }
}
}
```

**Second Class**

```
namespace TemperatureAverager
{
class TemperatureApp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] week = new double[7];    
        string[] days = new string[] { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" }; //array to track days of week
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) 
        {
            Console.Write("What was the temperature on " + days[x] + "?: ");
            string userTemperatureInput = Console.ReadLine();
            week[x] = double.Parse(userTemperatureInput);
        }
        Console.Write("How cold is too cold?: ");
        string userThreshInput = Console.ReadLine();    
        double thresh = double.Parse(userThreshInput);
        Temperatures weekOne = new Temperatures(week, thresh);  
        Console.WriteLine(weekOne.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You set lowest to 0 and highest to 5 at the start. You should also use auto properties to save those extra 11 lines per property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class one

```
public class Temperatures
{
    private double sum;
    private int daysInWeek;

    public double[] WeeksTemperatures { get; set; }
    public double ThreshTemp { get; set; }
    public double Average { get; set; }
    public double AverageExcludingLowest { get; set; }
    public double Highest { get; set; }
    public double Lowest { get; set; }
    public int NumOfThreshs { get; set; }

    public Temperatures(double[] wTemperatures, double threshT)
    {
        this.WeeksTemperatures = wTemperatures;
        this.ThreshTemp = threshT;
        sum = 0.0;
        daysInWeek = 7;
    }

    public void GetWeekStatistics()
    {
        GetSum();
        DetermineLowest();
        DetermineHighest();
        DetermineAverage();
        DetermineAverageExcludingLowest();
        DetermineNumberOfThreshs();
    }

    private void GetSum()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < daysInWeek; x++) //Traverse through the week's temperatures
        {
            this.sum = this.sum + this.WeeksTemperatures[x];
        }
    }

    public void DetermineLowest()
    {
        this.Lowest = this.WeeksTemperatures[0];
        for (int x = 0; x < daysInWeek; x++) //Traverse through the week's temperatures
        {
            if (this.WeeksTemperatures[x] < this.Lowest)   //find the lowest temperature of the week
            {
                this.Lowest = this.WeeksTemperatures[x];   //and set it to lowest
            }
        }
    }

    public void DetermineHighest()
    {
        this.Highest = this.WeeksTemperatures[0];
        for (int x = 0; x < daysInWeek; x++) //Traverse through the week's temperatures
        {
            if (this.WeeksTemperatures[x] > this.Highest)  //find the highest temperature of the week
            {
                this.Highest = this.WeeksTemperatures[x];  //and set it to highest
            }
        }
    }

    private void DetermineAverage()
    {
        this.Average = this.sum / daysInWeek;
    }

    public void DetermineAverageExcludingLowest()
    {
        this.AverageExcludingLowest = ((this.sum - this.Lowest) / daysInWeek);   // calculate average excluding lowest temperature
    }

    public void DetermineNumberOfThreshs()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < daysInWeek; x++) //Traverse through the week's temperatures
        {
            if (this.WeeksTemperatures[x] < this.ThreshTemp)   //find the lowest temperature of the week
            {
                this.NumOfThreshs++;
            }
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "=====================\nWeekly Statistics\n" + "---------------------\n" + "Average Temperature: " + this.Average + "\nHighest Temperature: "
        + this.Highest + "\nLowest Temperature: " + this.Lowest + "\nAvg. Excl. Lowest: " + this.AverageExcludingLowest + "\n# of Cold Days: " + this.NumOfThreshs + "\n====================="; //Formats and the invoice to be printed
    }
}
```

Change in class two

```
Temperatures weekOne = new Temperatures(week, thresh);
weekOne.GetWeekStatistics();
```

Comment: Whoa. I was currently still working on this  and didn't expect anyone else to attempt to answer but thank you!

Comment: I just realized there is a slight error after testing it a bit. It seems to ignore the highest number and the lowest number when displaying results. Only being correct sometimes.

Comment: @Larry have updated the code. Please try and let me know.

Comment: It fixed the highest and lowest. I did two more testings though and it seems it messes up the average when excluding the lowest temp

Comment: It giving an average that is lower than the normal calculated one and it should probably be higher.

Comment: @Larry
assume average = 63
number of days = 7
lowest temp = 7

avg = 63/7 = 9
avgExcludingLowest = (63-7)/7 = 8

going by this, code is correct. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Larry, Output
What was the temperature on Sunday?: 30
What was the temperature on Monday?: 5
What was the temperature on Tuesday?: 4
What was the temperature on Wednesday?: 10
What was the temperature on Thursday?: 12
What was the temperature on Friday?: 55
What was the temperature on Saturday?: 22
How cold is too cold?: 12
=====================
Weekly Statistics
---------------------
Average Temperature: 19.7142857142857
Highest Temperature: 55
Lowest Temperature: 4
Avg. Excl. Lowest: 19.1428571428571
# of Cold Days: 3
=====================

Comment: I guess that does make sense. Maybe I was looking at this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have 7 all over the code. Make it a constant like 
public static int DaysCount = 7 on the Tempratures class and reference that whenever needed (see example below).

```
class Temperatures
{
  public static int DaysCount = 7;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] week = new double[Temperatures.DaysCount];    
    }
```

I can't see where you run the Determine...() functions, så the values are never calculated.

In the Determine...() functions you should set the value to an appropriate initial value before you run the loop as in:

```
public double DetermineHighest()
{
  highest = -273 // degrees

  for (int x = 0; x < DaysCount; x++) //Traverse through the week's temperatures
  {
    if (weeksTemperatures[x] > highest)  //find the highest temperature of the week
    {
      highest = weeksTemperatures[x];  //and set it to highest
    }
  }
  return highest;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll edit around and see if I can make it work better